# image modal with reactjs using javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am tring to open a image modal on clicking the image.I am getting a list of image from the restapi.But my page shows nothing when its rendered.I am using this link as reference: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_modal_img

```
getAllProjectRequirementImageList = () => {
    axios.get(this.state.apiUrl+'/api/v1/visitRequirement/getAllByProjectId', {
        params: {   projectId: this.state.projectId }
    }).then((response) => {
        console.log("get with list ImageData",response.data.data);
        this.setState({ ioImageListing: response.data.data  });
    }).catch((error)=>{  console.log("error",error); this.setState({ ioImageListing: []  });   });
};




 componentDidMount() {
    console.log('componentDidMount colling ...');
    this.getAllProjectRequirementImageList();
    // responsive
    var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

    // Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
    var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
    var modalImg = document.getElementById('img01');
    var captionText = document.getElementById('caption');

    if (img) {
      img.onclick = () => {
        modal.style.display = 'block';
        modalImg.src = this.src;
        captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
      };
    }

    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName('close')[0];
    span.onclick = () => {
      modal.style.display = 'none';
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          {this.state.ioImageListing.map((io, key) => {
            io.visitRequirementList.map((skill, j) => (
              <img
                id="myImg"
                src={
                  this.state.apiUrl +
                  '/api/v1/visitImageRequirementInfo/getImageByImagePathId?imagePath=' +
                  skill.imagePath
                }
                alt="Snow"
                style={width:"100%";maxWidth:"300px"}
              />
            ));
          })}
        </div>

        <div id="myModal" className="modal">
          <div>
            <span className="close">&times;</span>
            <img className="modal-content" id="img01" />
            <div id="caption"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

and this is the json response i am getting from backend:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "8c83ac41-13b2-4827-96bc-dd251c4cf929",
      "visitLocation": "bedroom",
      "visitRequirementList": [
        {

          "imagePath": "visitImageDirectory/332c3b83-82d3-45b6-9660-309ebc3f246d.png",

        },
        {

          "imagePath": "visitImageDirectory/332c3b83-82d3-45b6-9660-309ebc3f246d.png",

        }

      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "05c36c21-adc6-4fa3-9609-b3dea67b9e69",
      "visitLocation": "kitchen",
      "visitRequirementList": [
        {

          "imagePath": "visitImageDirectory/7678f04c-22bd-4735-9f7d-8c34db31b714.png"

        },

      ]
    }
  ],
  "message": "data Found",
  "status": "success"
}
```

How can i show a list of images in a modal calling data from restapi.My restapi works fine.Any help regarding this would be appreciated.

Comment: a tip when developing in react is to use a library like [Material UI](https://material-ui.com/components/modal/) they have tons of usefull prebuilt components that you can just pass data to. Check the link for modal examples

Comment: Can you please add the code of the function `getAllProjectRequirementImageList`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many things you are doing the non-react way in this example. First of all, here's my solution for your problem:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class extends Component {
  state = {
    showModal: false,
    caption: '',
    modalSrc: '',

    // ...rest of your state
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getAllProjectRequirementImageList();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          {this.state.ioImageListing.map((io, key) => {
            io.visitRequirementList.map((skill, j) => {
              const src = `${this.state.apiUrl}/api/v1/visitImageRequirementInfo/getImageByImagePathId?imagePath=${skill.imagePath}`;
              const alt = 'Snow'; // or whatever
              return (
                <img
                  id="myImg"
                  src={src}
                  onClick={() => {
                    this.setState({ showModal: true, caption: alt, modalSrc: src });
                  }}
                  alt={alt}
                  style={{ width: '100%', maxWidth: '300px' }}
                />
              );
            });
          })}
        </div>

        <div
          id="myModal"
          className="modal"
          style={{ display: this.state.showModal ? 'block' : 'none' }}
        >
          <div>
            <span className="close" onClick={() => this.setState({ showModal: false })}>
              &times;
            </span>
            <img className="modal-content" id="img01" src={this.state.modalSrc} />
            <div id="caption">
              {this.state.caption}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

For me the main takedowns from this are:

1. In React, if you want to access the DOM, you should never do it with `getElementById`, `querySelector` or any other vanilla javascript DOM manipulation methods. Instead, you should use [React Ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html). Mind you, you shouldn't use refs at all unless it's the only option.
2. If you want to change style on click, especially stuff like hide and show modal, the easiest way to do so would be by using state and defining a style that depend on that state, just like I did in the modal.
3. React has its own events. Javascript's regular `onclick` changes to React's `onClick`. You can read more about it [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html).

Hope this code works for you. Let me know how it goes or if you need anything else.

Comment: thank you it worked for me.The `const src ` is not working.So i directly linked the api in the `src` attribute and `modalsrc` attribute.now its working fine.Basically  i want to make  a lightbox slider.I hope thats a good start.Thanks for your help and tips.

Answer (score 1):

You should read again about rules and conventions when developing applications with React.
 First, avoid using DOM manipulation directly like the way you modifying Modal element. Please do it in a React way. Try something like this:

```
<div id="myModal" className="modal" style={this.state.isShowModal ? "block" : "none"}>
          <div>
            <span className="close">&times;</span>
            <img className="modal-content" id="img01" src={this.state.displayImgSrc}/>
            <div id="caption">{this.state.displayImgCaption}</div>
          </div>
</div>
```

And then move your `myImg` click event handler outside of `componenDidMount`. Make it a separated function and use it to directly bind when render from image list.

```
io.visitRequirementList.map((skill, j) => (
          <img
            id="myImg"
            src={
              this.state.apiUrl +
              '/api/v1/visitImageRequirementInfo/getImageByImagePathId?imagePath=' +
              skill.imagePath
            }
            onClick={this.imageClick}
            alt="Snow"
            style={width:"100%";maxWidth:"300px"}
          />
        ));
```

Of course, inside `imageClick` you should implement logic by changing React state instead of direct manipulation.
Hope this can help